# How to only import new files to Access DB with existing VBA code

Tags: excel, loops, ms-access, vba

I have some VBA code which i'm using to import specific columns of a Excel spreadsheet into my Access Database.

The files being imported to the database are produced every working day, and I plan on running the import process at the start of each week.

The problem I am facing is that my current code imports every spreadsheet in the directory, rather than just the new ones produced the previous week. The files being imported are named in the following format: "FD Worksheet 01 07 2016", with the date section being the date that it was generated on. In the database there is a field called "file_date" as can be seen in the code below, this is where the date of the file is stored when it is imported to the database to be able to identify what file the data came from.

Could someone please help me modify my code to only import the spreadsheets that are missing from my database? I.e. Search through the database first to check if the file was previously imported, and if so ignore it?

Many thanks.

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function importExcelSheets()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim astrPieces() As String
Dim dteFileDate As Date
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strInsert As String
Dim Directory As String
Dim TableName As String

Directory = "F:\FD Worksheets\jul 2016"
TableName = "FD Worksheets"

Dim strTable As String
Dim I As Long
I = 0

 If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
     strDir = Directory & "\"
 Else
     strDir = Directory
 End If
 strFile = '" strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.XLSX")      

 While strFile <> ""
     I = I + 1
     Debug.Print "importing " & strFile

If Not strDir Like "*\" Then
    strDir = strDir & "\"
End If
strInsert = "INSERT INTO [FD Worksheets] (file_date, Prod, Average_Cost, WSP)" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT [which_date] as file_date, xl.Prod, xl.Average_Cost, xl.WSP" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=" & strDir & strFile & "].[Sheet1$] AS xl;"
Debug.Print strInsert
astrPieces = Split(Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 5), " ")
dteFileDate = DateSerial(Val(astrPieces(4)), astrPieces(3), astrPieces(2))
Debug.Print dteFileDate
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strInsert)
qdf.Parameters("which_date").Value = dteFileDate
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError

     strFile = Dir()
Wend

End Function
```

Comment: Would it not be simpler to move the XLSX to an archive folder after you've appended its data?  And then next time you run this procedure, the source folder will contain only XLSX files which have not been imported.

Comment: You make a fair point, I am likely over complicating this. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an if clause with a week number, try the below code, it's untested

```
Option Compare Database

Public Function importExcelSheets()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim astrPieces() As String
Dim dteFileDate As Date
Dim strDir As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strInsert As String
Dim Directory As String
Dim TableName As String

Directory = "F:\FD Worksheets\jul 2016"
TableName = "FD Worksheets"

Dim strTable As String
Dim I As Long
I = 0

 If Right(Directory, 1) <> "\" Then
     strDir = Directory & "\"
 Else
     strDir = Directory
 End If
 strFile = '" strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.XLSX")      

 While strFile <> ""


     'Add This Line
     if Format(Mid(strfile, 14, 10), "ww") = format(date(), "ww") -1 then


     I = I + 1
     Debug.Print "importing " & strFile

If Not strDir Like "*\" Then
    strDir = strDir & "\"
End If
strInsert = "INSERT INTO [FD Worksheets] (file_date, Prod, Average_Cost, WSP)" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT [which_date] as file_date, xl.Prod, xl.Average_Cost, xl.WSP" & vbCrLf & _
    "FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;DATABASE=" & strDir & strFile & "].[Sheet1$] AS xl;"
Debug.Print strInsert
astrPieces = Split(Left(strFile, Len(strFile) - 5), " ")
dteFileDate = DateSerial(Val(astrPieces(4)), astrPieces(3), astrPieces(2))
Debug.Print dteFileDate
Set db = CurrentDb
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, strInsert)
qdf.Parameters("which_date").Value = dteFileDate
qdf.Execute dbFailOnError
'and this one
end if
     strFile = Dir()
Wend

End Function
```